# Creating a map from game to guide with Leaflet or OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet

I have a quick question regarding the creation of a map with either OpenLayers or Leaflet.

I am trying to find a way I could use a program to create some points of interest, mostly personals points of interest. I will post some links to websites that have done it:

- https://dofus-map.com/
- [ESOhead](http://www.esohead.com/map#7.2.50.50.8:10:12:14:15:20:24:30:34:35:36:66:67:68:69:2:70:71:7:6:4:1:16:17)

There are many more websites like this. I am trying to do this for ESO, just a little project as a hobby. I am not sure which one of the two options I listed above would be the best to accomplish this project.

I am new on Javascript, the reason I am doing this is to learn a new skill and learn a new language.

If anyone has another alternative, please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you consider to use umap? Is a software that let you to add points and lines to the OSM layers..

https://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/

I think is not what you want but maybe.

If what you want is to code a map from scratch, I used leaflet and works very nice (is showing 15000 point of interest on our app)